# No se guarda la ruta de la imagen en Laravel al utilizar Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web con Laravel y Firebase Storage para guardar imágenes de establecimientos. He seguido varios tutoriales y he logrado cargar las imágenes en Firebase Storage correctamente. Sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas para guardar la ruta de la imagen en la base de datos de Laravel.

He utilizado JavaScript para cargar la imagen en Firebase Storage y obtener la URL de descarga. Luego, he intentado guardar la ruta de la imagen en el campo correspondiente de mi tabla de establecimientos en Laravel.

El problema es que, aunque la imagen se carga correctamente en Firebase Storage, la ruta de la imagen no se guarda en la base de datos de Laravel. No se produce ningún error, pero al intentar guardar los datos del formulario, obtengo el siguiente error: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'foto' cannot be null".

```
<form action="{{ route('establecimiento.store') }}" class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-2 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4" id="tuFormulario" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" id="rutaInput" name="ruta" value="">
    <input required autocomplete="off" style="width: 100%;" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="imageInput" name="foto" type="file">
</form>
```

```js
    
function uploadImage() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById("imageInput");
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var storageRef = storage.ref();
  var imagesRef = storageRef.child("fotoestablecimiento/" + file.name);

  var uploadTask = imagesRef.put(file);

  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    function(snapshot) {
      // Manejar el progreso de la carga de la imagen si es necesario
    },
    function(error) {
      console.error("Error al cargar la imagen:", error);
    },
    function() {
      // La imagen se ha cargado exitosamente, obtener la URL de descarga
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        // Guardar la ruta de la imagen en Laravel
        saveImageRoute(url);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error al obtener la URL de descarga:", error);
      });
    }
  );
}

function saveImageRoute(url) {
  var rutaInput = document.getElementById("rutaInput");
  rutaInput.value = url;

  console.log("URL de la imagen:", url); // Agrega esta línea

  // Envía el formulario solo si la URL de la imagen existe
  if (url) {
    var form = document.getElementById("tuFormulario");
    form.submit();
  } else {
    console.error("La URL de la imagen no está disponible");
  }
}
```

**Controlador Laravel**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Validaciones y otros campos del formulario

    $establecimiento = new Establecimiento;
    // Asignar otros campos del formulario

    $establecimiento->foto = $request->input('ruta');
    
    $establecimiento->save();

    // Otras acciones después de guardar los datos

    return redirect()->back();
}
}
```

**Migracion**

```php
$table->string('foto');
```